# What is AppIdentityError: Wrong recipient?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-client

I have a simple Python server to verify Google oauth2 id_tokens.  When this code executes it throws the error `AppIdentityError: Wrong recipient`:

```
def verify():
    id_token = request.form['id_token']
    status = {}
    if id_token is not None:
        try:
            jwt = verify_id_token(id_token, config['google']['clientId'])
            status['valid'] = True
            status['jwt'] = jwt
        except AppIdentityError:
            status['valid'] = False
            status['message'] = "Invalid id token"
    pprint.pprint(status)
    response = make_response(json.dumps(status))
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    return response
```

What does `AppIdentityError: Wrong recipient` mean and how can I address it?

Answer (score 0):

The JWT that you are trying to verify includes an audience (`aud`) value. The error is the result of the `aud` value being mismatched with what is expected.

I'm not certain which library you're using, but in the identity-toolkit-python-client package the VerifyGitTotken function looks at the project_id and client_id values that are provided to verify the JWT.

When I encountered this error, it turned out that my gitkit-server-config.json file mismatched what was provided by the Google developers console. The values are provided on the API Manager >> Overview >> Identity Toolkit API page.

I corrected my json file, and the error went away.